# WordPress add meta description to pages

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I want to add meta description tag to my pages so that my website can be found for different search results. Since I don't have direct access to the pages I have no idea where to add it,

I have looked in the admin area aswell as possible ways to add it into the php files that I can access(header.php for instance), but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use wordpress plugin

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/
```

this plugin provide various direct option to add meta data, this is mostly used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

for setting you may access to admin page -> appearance -> customized 
put your description on site identity / tagline (120-160 character)

to make it printed on the page, put this between

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
```